# Use Shiny to choose column, equality, and value to filter by conditions

Tags: r, shiny, tidyverse, rlang

I'm creating a Shiny app where I'd like the user to be able to select a column and condition, resulting in the `input$COLUMN input$CONDITION input$VALUE` which can be used to filter a dataframe.

[image]

## Desired Output

`iris %>% filter(input$COLUMN input$CONDITION input$VALUE)` == `iris %>% filter(Sepal.Length > 4.7)`

For this to work I need to use rlang for the `input$COLUMN`, I need to `eval` the `input$CONDITION` and I need the `input$VALUE` to be converted to a numeric when appropriate. (I'm attempting this in my `verbatimTextOutput`)

**What is the best approach for achieving this? I thought making the whole expression a string to be parsed within a tidy pipeline may be the way to go but I am open to alternate suggestions!!**

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)


ui <- fluidPage(

   # Sidebar with an input for column
   # boolean input
   # and value input
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fluidRow(column(4, selectInput("COLUMN", "Filter By:", choices = colnames(iris))),
                 column(4, selectInput("CONDITION", "Boolean", choices = c("==", "!=", ">", "<"))),
                 column(4, uiOutput("COL_VALUE")))
      ),

      # Show text generated by sidebar
      # use text in tidy pipeline to create subsetted dataframe
      mainPanel(
         verbatimTextOutput("as_text"),
         tableOutput("the_data")
      )
   )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$COL_VALUE <- renderUI({
    x <- iris %>% select(!!sym(input$COLUMN))
    selectInput("VALUE", "Value", choices = x)
  })

  filtering_string <- reactive ({
    paste0("!!sym(", input$COLUMN, ") ", input$CONDITION, " ", input$VALUE)
  })

   output$as_text <- renderText({
     filtering_string()
   })


   output$the_data <- renderTable({
     iris %>%
       eval(parse(text = filtering_string()))
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not too familiar with `!!sym` but you could do:

```
  output$the_data <- renderTable({

    # To hide error when no value is selected
    if (input$VALUE == "") {
      my_data <- "" 
    } else {
      my_data <- iris %>% 
        filter(eval(parse(text = paste0(input$COLUMN, input$CONDITION, input$VALUE))))  
    }

    return(my_data)

  })
```